# Build an installer with prerequisite option

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, installation

I had made project in windows application, now I want to add custom launch condition for SQL Server Compact 3.5.

Can it will done with registry search? can it will done with component id search?

and if yes then how please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Visual Studio Web installer packager you need to use custom action and try to find registry version

Try below
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlservercompact/archive/2008/02/08/sql-server-compact-release-versions.aspx

I would suggest to go with Wix Installer, it gives you lot of flexibilty.

Comment: Link only answers (which this effectively is) aren't good answers. Can you please summarise the contents of the blog post you are linking to.

Comment: Chris,
Link will help him to find registry key from which further he can put prerequisite.
I have just pointed him to search registry key.
Probably he can do further to code around Custom Action.

I have been playing around with Wix a lot, so this can be achieved by Wix, however that depends on people easiness.